# Polymer: how to change a parent's property from a child?

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have a pretty simple set up where a parent component has a bunch of children components. The parent component has a pageTitle property that I'd like to update from whichever child component is being displayed.

So basically I have a header with a page title, which I'd like to update depending on which component is being displayed.

Here is the parent component:

```
<dom-module id="my-parent">

  <template>

      <h1>Page title: {{pageTitle}}</h1>

      <a on-tap="changePage" data-page="1">Go to page 1</a><br />
      <a on-tap="changePage" data-page="2">Go to Page 2</a>

      <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="data-page>
        <my-child1 data-page="1" page-title="{{pageTitle}}"></my-child1>
        <my-child2 data-page="2" page-title="{{pageTitle}}"></my-child2>
      </iron-pages>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-parent',
      properties: {
        page: {type: String, value: "1"},
        pageTitle: {type: String},
      },
      changePage: function(e) {
        var elm = e.currentTarget;
        this.page = elm.getAttribute("data-page");
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Here is an example of a child:

```
<dom-module id="my-child1">

  <template>
      <p>We are on page 1</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-child1',
      properties: {
        pageTitle: {type: String, notify: true, value="Page 1"},
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

So now, how can I achieve something like: "when my-child1 is displayed, update the parent's pageTitle property"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the solution. I had to use the attributeChanged event, and check the class name against "iron-selected".

Here is the child component that makes it work:

```
<dom-module id="my-child1">

  <template>
      <p>We are on page 1</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-child1',
      properties: {
        pageTitle: {type: String, notify: true},
      },
      attributeChanged: function(name, type) {
        if (name == "class" && this.getAttribute(name) == "iron-selected") {
          this.set("pageTitle", "Page 1");
        }
      },
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```